# Java file structure encryption

Tags: java, encryption

I've been reading up on how encryption works more or less and have used some in Java, but I've never seen people talk about encrypting a structure of a file. Mostly the contents.

For example:

This is a simple JSON file.

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

From what I understand, when you encrypt the data in the file, this happens (no actual encryption, just random letters for the sake of argument):

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "Alxqpowekjmzkx23aOSP",
  "value": "oaksdpmxzPOADPwAPSDl",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "AOPSDKPQPOASKdpxzlmmcvkds", "APOwpoqdxzmdas": "AQPOWKDpoAKsdmxz"},
      {"value": "OPWEkPAskpdkPAodAodkapdsk", "APOSkdpoaKpadkAP": "XpzZOpxdkapKDAPkd"},
      {"value": "OQIWdOmlzxmLZKmdAd", "AOPKSpokdASK": "PAOSKdpoasdkaposdkpzxl"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Basically, you don't know what the values are, but you can still see the structure and what types of data there is.

Is there a way to convert the whole file contents (including the structure) into a single string looking, for example, like this?

`AposdkPAdkPAOsdkPAOWKpo2kdpoaKD2od1dkSAOd9asdkPAOskd93kaoldkPA92dkPAOSdk92`

Or perhaps something of this sort? But with Java, because most of the time to produce it like this, I've read that people use external tools, a la VeraCrypt and the sort, but I'd like to know how it's done/what tools are used in Java and do it myself programmatically.

[image: Image1]

Comment: "From what I understand, when you encrypt the data in the file, this happens" - that entirely depends on how you encrypt it. The most common ways of encrypting a file *do* just encrypt everything in it, leaving no sign of the structure visible.

Comment: What method of encryption are you using that just encrypts certain values in a JSON file?

Comment: @khelwood Well, usually just encrypt a value, convert it to Base64 (so I have it as a string) and write that in the file. I'm fairly new to doing this properly, but it is what I've been thought, which is why I'm trying to find a way to do the whole content.

Comment: @DoombringerBG If you were to google _how to encrypt a file in Java_ you would find lots of links to get you started.

Comment: @khelwood I've already done that and keep doing it. Problem is, I keep finding useless information and examples where people only encrypt the values but not the whole structure/content of a file.

Comment: read file data as byte array(in your case all the whole of them!, not just the parts which would be corresponding to some values if you json parse them) , feed them to the encryption algorithm then write the resulted data to a file. and unless you're using some weird file system standard which only allows strings to be written to disk base64 wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be Googling for encryption/decryption far too specific towards **JSON** rather than towards **Text File**. If you want to encrypt a Text File which just so happens to contain JSON content then the internet is full of examples including SO. Never the less, here are some method that will carry out the task.

The file content encryption provided here utilizes Java 8's [Base64](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_base64.htm) Class encoding and then a [Caesar Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) (which is a shift cipher) is applied to each file line. **By no means is this considered a Secure Encryption** but it is enough to confuse most (at least for a wee bit).

The concept here is to read in the JSON text file one line at a time. As each line is read in it is encoded, ciphered then saved to a Destination File Path until the end of file is reached. When finished you will see that in no way is the destination file legible towards what type of file the original may have been, at least not until is is Decrypted. All text is ciphered including format indentation. File Decryption is done in the very same fashion.

There are four simple methods provided here which requires Java 8+ to carry out the task of encryption/decryption:

> To Encode and Cipher a string:

```
/**
 * *** THIS METHOD BY NO MEANS PROVIDES A SECURE ENCRYPTION ***<BR><BR>
 * <p>
 * This is an extremely easy String encryption algorithm that encodes the
 * supplied string to Base64 then applies a Caesar Cipher (which is a shift
 * cipher). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher<br><br>
 * <p>
 * You MUST use the provided easyDecrypt() method to decrypt a string that
 * has been encrypted with this method.<br><br>
 *
 * @param inputString (String) The string to encrypt.<br>
 *
 * @return (String) The encrypted string.<br>
 */
public static String easyEncrypt(String inputString) {
    try {
        String b64encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(inputString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        // Reverse the string
        String reverse = new StringBuffer(b64encoded).reverse().toString();

        StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
        final int OFFSET = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length(); i++) {
            tmp.append((char) (reverse.charAt(i) + OFFSET));
        }
        return tmp.toString();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

> To Decode and Decipher a string:

```
/**
 * This method is used to decrypt string that have been encrypted with the
 * provided easyEncrypt() method.<br><br>
 * <p>
 * Simply supply the encrypted string.<br><br>
 *
 * @param inputString (String) The encrypted string which was created by the
 *                    easyEncrypt() Method.<br>
 *
 * @return (String) The original string decrypted.<br>
 */
public static String easyDecrypt(String inputString) {
    StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
    final int OFFSET = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
        tmp.append((char) (inputString.charAt(i) - OFFSET));
    }

    String reversed = new StringBuffer(tmp.toString()).reverse().toString();
    return new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(reversed));
}
```

> To Encrypt A File:

```
public void encryptFile(String sourceFilePath, String destinationFilePath) {
    try {    
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(sourceFilePath)); 
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(destinationFilePath))) {
            String line;
            while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = reader.nextLine();
                String encryptedLine = easyEncrypt(line);
                writer.write(encryptedLine + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

> To Decrypt A File:

```
public void decryptFile(String sourceFilePath, String destinationFilePath) {
    try {    
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(sourceFilePath)); 
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(destinationFilePath))) {
            String line;
            while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = reader.nextLine();
                String decryptedLine = easyDecrypt(line);
                writer.write(decryptedLine + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> To use the above methods:

```
encryptFile("SimpleJSON.txt", "NewEncryptedFile.txt");
```

With the sample JSON content you provided within your post, the desitnation file content will look like:

```
AA{iksnM59[^xN}i
wMW^wpq^mEmSmU[emEGM
wMW^wpqVmEmSmY[hwJqhmEGM
;FmSmE\h{=KgmEGM
AwJM:MWfpV\e59[^xNGMkEGM
AAEP=NWOsQ6fIh\^SZKhlZqgHNGM:M}enpKfn96fmEGPmg\^SNGM:MW^5|[]6N}ikEGMkEGM
w4rMtk}]zVofpF7XmEmSmw6]t|6]y=qMk{mMyZKgTNGM:MW^5|[]6N}ikEGMkEGM
AAUjmoGOn=KVpR7fwRoMksnMvR[ewRqfzNGMwMW^~=KfHNGM:MW^5|[]6N}ikEGMkEGM
A4JMkEGM
=FGM
A4\j
```

And now to Decrypt this file:

```
decryptFile("NewEncryptedFile.txt", "DecryptedFile.txt");
```

The decrypted destination file will look like:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something like this! I think I'll mix this with Google Tink as well. It should be pretty safe. <3